# Changing Select Clause of an Access Query in a VBA loop

Tags: loops, ms-access, parameters, vba

I'm trying to loop through a few queries in Access (2007-2010) and the first query grabs a different field from a table each time. How do I put a "parameter" in the select clause of the SQL statement so that each time it runs the query it will grab the correct field? It doesn't recognize the field name if I put [ ] around it to enter a parameter--it will just enter that name in each record.

Here's a simplified illustration of what I'm trying to describe:

```
SELECT 
    Base.Trial, 
    Base.Timestep, 
    Base.Rate3, 
    Base.CashIndex  
FROM 
    Mthly20141231Base AS Base  
ORDER BY 
    Base.Trial, 
    Base.Timestep
```

Each time VBA loops back to this first query, I want it to run the same thing but instead of Base.Rate3 I want Base.Rate12

I don't want to have to type the SQL code in VBA.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE-Here is my code for the alternative since Access doesn't support what I want it to do:

```
Sub LoopTesting()

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim RS_Inputs As Recordset
    Dim increment As Long
    Dim increment_prev As Long
    Dim QueryString As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'This table has my increments I want to loop through
    Set RS_Inputs = db.OpenRecordset("Test Periods")

    RS_Inputs.MoveFirst
    increment_prev = RS_Inputs("Timestep Increments")

    Do Until RS_Inputs.EOF

        increment = RS_Inputs("Timestep Increments")
        QueryString = Replace(GetQueryStr("RatesbyTimestep"), increment_prev, increment)
        db.QueryDefs("RatesbyTimestep").SQL = QueryString
        increment_prev = increment
        Call DeleteTable
        db.Execute "Step 3 - MakeTable"
        Call UpdatePrice(increment)

        RS_Inputs.MoveNext

    Loop

    'reset query back to first increment
    QueryString = Replace(GetQueryStr("RatesbyTimestep"), 360, 3)
    db.QueryDefs("RatesbyTimestep").SQL = QueryString

End Sub
```

Comment: After hours of Google searching, I have come to the same conclusion that you just can't do it -- see code I updated above. I think I have found a solution. My query is set up so that I can use the Replace function in the loop. So in my illustration, it will replace 3 with 12, and so on and then replace back to 3 at the end. It's working so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have been making PTQ  (Pass Thru Queries) and they do not edit the column names vs any table at creation time but rather at run time.  I can have

```
ptq_xxx as  "Select ID,  @arg1, DTS  From myTable Where DTS >= @arg2."
sSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ptq_xxx").sql  
sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "@arg1", myNewFieldName)
sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "@arg2", myDateValue)
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset, nRecAffected As Long
Set rst = myConn.Execute(sSQL, nRecAffected)
```

Works like a charm.